# FileReader returns empty on data blob

Tags: javascript, filereader

I'm attempting to read some data that is in a blob from an api call.  The blob is not an image but a group of data that I need.  I've seen several examples on blob images but not too many on just plain data.

My method is like so:

```
  getTemplatesMainDB = () => {
    SecureStore.getItemAsync('authToken')
    .then((authToken) => authToken)
    .then((token) => fetch('https://example.com/live2/api/reports/templatesall?token=' + token))
    .then((response) => response.blob())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      let fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = function(e) {
        console.log(fileReader.result)
      }
      fileReader.readAsText(responseJson);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
```

From fetch I'm handling the data as response.blob()
Then I activate the file reader and after I attempt to console.log.  My console.log has not log of this.  Nothing happens.
I've also tried this: `console.log(e.target.result)`

I'm not even sure if I'm doing it right.  Any ideas?

Comment: What is the SecureStore class/object? What is the .blob() method? Those aren't native JS methods, so wouldn't you need to look at their documentation first?

Comment: Sorry that's an option in expo where I'm running this method. .blob() is part of the api: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob @JordanRieger

Comment: It seems like the Body class ("mixin"?) is where that .blob() method comes from, and it's related to the Fetch API, which is some kind of replacement for the XMLHttpRequest class. But what is expo?

Comment: Expo is to build react native apps.  The fetch api is pretty common with js.  @JordanRieger

Comment: Can you put some console logs in the promise chain leading up to the FileReader part? Try to use those to verify if each of the objects is not null, e.g. authToken, token, response, responseJson. Can you use F12 Network tab (or a network analyzer, if you're not in a browser) to verify that your HTTPS call is actually returning data? P.S. I think you should update your question to specify all the technologies you're using. Your problem is likely specific to the Expo/Fetch/Body APIs and not vanilla JavaScript/FileReader as your tags specify.